# Is it possible to execute the jar file without main method in java

Tags: java, cookies, jar, session-cookies, executable-jar

I've created java project in my eclipse without main method & right-clicked project, export as jar and created. Now am trying to execute the jar from CMD, but it is showing error.
no main manifest attribute, in executecookie.jar

Even I've tried the below commands in CMD:
`java -jar executecookie.jar
java -jar executecookie.jar com.cookie.CookieApp`
My Code is:
`public class CookieApp {
public static String CookieMethod()
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/SD_WorkspaceNew/CookieJar/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://localhost:8080/qcbin/rest/is-authenticated?login-form-required=y");
.......

return CookieResult;

}
}`

Is this possible to execute the jar file from CMD without main method? if it is yes, how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error not because you don't have a main method. It's because you don't have a manifest file and other required attributes for properly packaged jar file. Check [JAR file specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) for more details.

> Is this possible to execute the jar file from CMD without main method?
>   if it is yes, how can i resolve this issue?

Did you try executing other jar files in your system?

```
java -jar file.jar
```

This command is indeed the correct way to execute a jar file.

Comment: I've manifest.txt file and mentioned the package,class name also